# Ember.js : outlet does not replace the view after operation completes

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data

This is my application structure. http://jsfiddle.net/cc7fC/

- contacts
- contacts/new
- contact/<id> //contact
- contact/<id>/edit

I am trying to load "new", "contact" & "contact.edit" into a same {{outlet}}. After I complete editing and hit save. The view does not refresh until I manually click a contact.

```
...
submit: function(post) {
      post.get('store').commit();
      if (post.didCreate) {
        //debugger;
        return this.transitionTo('contact');
      }
...
```

Edit: fixed typos & format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here.

You can't place `contact` and `contact.edit` in the same `{{outlet}}`, because `contact.edit` is nested inside `contact`.  Moreover, you can't transition from `contact.edit` to `contact` because `contact.edit` is nested inside `contact`.

What you can do however, is place `contact.index` and `contact.edit` in the same `outlet`, and you can transition between them.  So you need to replace the `contact` template with a `contact.index` template and define the route behavior for `App.ContactIndexRoute`.

The second issue is when you transition to a `model` route such as `contact` which is now `contact.index`, you need to pass the model that you want it to transition to. So the transition should look like this:

```
this.transitionTo('contact.index', contact);
```

One more thing, I'm not sure why you are using :

```
if (post.didCreate) {
}
```

I don't think this works... didCreate is an event that you need to listen to.
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981500/transition-after-saving-model-of-ember-data/14982675#14982675).

And finally the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/cc7fC/3/) :)

Comment: This worked great. Thx for fixing the code. About the post.didCreate, I have no idea about it. I am using multiple examples of emberjs to create my app. that particular code came from - http://waltermcginnis.com/site/topics/show/82-modal-forms-in-emberjs